# Android: Positioning drawable using drawableleft and drawableright

Tags: android, drawable

In my application I'm using a lot of drawableleft and drawableright attributes.
I have a large handful of them within buttons, and two of them are within text views.

I am able to position the drawables within buttons using padding left and padding right. I am trying to do the same within the text views, but the drawables aren't being re positioned. I also tried to use margin on the textviews in case the drawables were being placed outside of the textview rather than inside.

**Example of button with drawable left attribute with padding on left and right**

```
        <Button android:id="@+id/upgradeButton3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/iconcoin"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            style="@style/DarkButtonLightText"/>
```

[image: Button with drawable left]

**Example of textview with drawable left attribute with padding on left and right**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textViewCash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/backButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/iconcoin"
    style="@style/HeaderTextDark"/>
```

[image]

As you can see, the button's drawable clearly has positioning, while the textview's doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: You're wrapping the width of the `TextView`, but you've got a definite width on the `Button`. I'm guessing that's causing the difference.

Comment: @MikeM.

Edit: It seemed to fix it within the view inside android studio, but on the actual AVD and on my device as well, it still behaves as before.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.